# How do deep-space spacecraft and space stations protect the crew and electronic equipment from radiation during long-duration missions?

Tags: spacecraft, radiation, cosmic-radiation

> **Question:** How would a deep-space spacecraft protect its crew and electronics from cosmic radiation, solar wind, and solar events?

I'm trying to design a hypothetical space station and have been doing research on what it would take to create a sustainable space craft. One major issue is radiation from cosmic rays and solar flares.

Water is effective at absorbing radiation, but I can't figure out a way to have the water flow on the exterior of the spacecraft without freezing or boiling off. Another option would be to use reinforced polyethylene as the outer layer since polyethylene contains a high concentration of hydrogen, which is good at absorbing radiation and not creating a secondary wave.

However, how would polyethylene protect against solar flares and cosmic rays, which contain an immense amount of energy?

Comment: @FrankW. I used to do that all the time, now I never begin to write the title until everything else is done I'm ready to post.

Comment: @uhoh Hm... you know, I probably should start doing that

Comment: Just put the water in tanks.

Comment: @ikrase On the outside of the space station? Along every side?

Comment: @RecordTime yes! a lot of..like 10m in every direction. I am sure you will find a lot googleing about water as a radiation shield ....i am not posting this as an answer, because I have no sources at hand. But till now, no such shields were used. It is still a topic for discussion for future mars missions. LEO Space Stations are inside earths magentic field and Apollo Astronauts just died significantly earlier.

Comment: @CallMeTom I never considered water in every direction a feasible plan, it didn't seem very feasible to launch tons and tons of water into space for the purpose of protection.

Comment: @RecordTime: and that is the reason, why it is not been used, yet. And why protection for mars-missions is still a topic.

Comment: Use funghi on the outside of the station/craft: https://phys.org/news/2020-07-chernobyl-fungi-shield-astronauts.html It grows in space, so you have a self-repairing shield and don#t need to carry the shield all the way from earth - provided you can wait until the shield has grown enough. However, this doesn't protect against high-energy impacts. I don't think we'll get the tech in the near future to be able to deal with that.

Comment: A popular design in hard SF is to have a "storm shelter" at the centre of the vehicle, surrounded by tankage for whatever water is needed for the mission, hydroponic gardens, etc., just big enough to hold the crew for 24h or so without too much discomfort. They would retreat there when a solar flare or similar was expected.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be either on the outside or an entire 10m thick. 

Not just in SF, this was how that enormous Mars mission with like six NERVAS was going to work.